# Bitmap is not showing up totally and there is no out of memory exception

Tags: android, bitmap

i want to display a clock and its hands on the screen using customized view .
i am doing it this way as i want to change the orientation of the hands of the clock later in the code.

code -

```
public class Clockwork extends Activity{



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MyViews mv=new MyViews(this);
        LinearLayout l1=new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout l2=new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout l3=new LinearLayout(this);
        ScrollView sc=new ScrollView(this);
        Button b1=new Button(this);
        Button b2=new Button(this);
        TimePicker tp=new TimePicker(this);

        b1.setText("Okay");
        b2.setText("Cancle");
        l3.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        l3.addView(b1, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        l3.addView(b2, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        l2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        l2.addView(tp);
        l2.addView(l3,new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        l1.addView(mv,new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        l1.addView(l2);
        sc.addView(l1,new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        this.setContentView(sc);

    }
class MyViews extends ImageView{

    Bitmap clock,mh,hh;
    public MyViews(Context context) {
        super(context);
        clock=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.clock, null);
        hh=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.hhand, null);
        mh=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.mhand, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(clock, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mh, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(hh, 0, 0, null);
        super.onDraw(canvas);

    }

}


}
```

output -
[image]

and this is what the logcat says -

```
12-24 14:11:06.178: I/dalvikvm(281): Could not find method android.widget.Button.setBackground, referenced from method sarath.apps.SiLeNcE.MainActivity.mtv
12-24 14:11:06.178: W/dalvikvm(281): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3984: Landroid/widget/Button;.setBackground (Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;)V
12-24 14:11:06.238: D/dalvikvm(281): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0018
12-24 14:11:06.248: D/dalvikvm(281): VFY: dead code 0x001b-0049 in Lsarath/apps/SiLeNcE/MainActivity;.mtv (Landroid/view/View;)V
12-24 14:11:17.660: D/dalvikvm(281): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5424 objects / 315672 bytes in 55ms
12-24 14:11:53.428: W/KeyCharacterMap(281): No keyboard for id 0
12-24 14:11:53.428: W/KeyCharacterMap(281): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
12-24 14:16:47.358: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(281): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
12-24 14:16:53.058: D/dalvikvm(281): GC_EXPLICIT freed 5122 objects / 263048 bytes in 183ms
```

what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: replace with canvas.drawBitmap(clock,clock.getHeight(), 0, null);

Comment: why isnt the bitmap showing up totally ? @blackbelt

Comment: did you used setBackground anywhere in your code?

Comment: no i didnt set background

Comment: just use the xml editor to create your view hierarchy .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your canvas is bigger than your view. You need to change the view size by using [setLayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutParams%28android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29).

Comment: if thats the case do u have any idea what would happened to the buttons and time picker i have added with my view ?

Comment: @sarath You can't add view to view, you can add view to layout. I don't understand your question.

Comment: i mean i have added 2 buttons and my customized view to a linearlayout  and set it as the contentview .The 2 buttons dont show up too. do u know y ?

Comment: @sarath Your problem is the view size, it's ether to small or to big. I bet that if you first add the buttons and than your view, you will see the buttons.

Comment: awesome i changed this 
l1.addView(mv,new LayoutParams(clock.getHeight(),clock.getHeight()));
i get the whole clock but not the buttons